# Email sending error in Codeigniter " fwrite(): send of 6 bytes failed with errno=10054 An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host."

Tags: php, codeigniter

**Want to handle the situation when the smtp host server is restarted while sending emails. Emails sending script should not get terminated due to the runtime error. It should try to reconnect to server host and send the emails again**

My Code :

```
$config=array('protocol'=>'smtp',
                'smtp_host'=>'example.com',     
                'smtp_port'=>587,
                'smtp_user'=>'******',
                'smtp_pass'=>'***', 
                'priority'=> 1,
                'smtp_timeout'=>'30',
                //'smtp_keepalive'=>TRUE,
                'mailtype'  => 'html',              
                'charset'=>'utf-8',
                'wordwrap'=>True);  
 foreach($res2 as $email)
{
  $this->email->from($fromemail,$fromname);
                
                $this->email->to($email);              
                $this->email->subject('Dummy Email');               
                $body=$emailDesign2;
                $this->email->message($body);
                
                
                
                
                                
                    if($this->email->send())
                    {
                        echo "Mail Sent<br/>";
                        $total++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                         echo "Mail Not Sent";
                    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a function and when the sending failed call the function again here is the idea.

```
function send_email($class, $details){

    $total = 0;

    $class->from($details['fromemail'], $details['fromname']);
                
    $class->to($details['email']);              
    $class->subject('Dummy Email');               
    $body = $datails['body'];
    $class->message($body);
                
    if($class->send()) {
        echo "Mail Sent<br/>";
        $total++;
    } else {
       send_email($class, $details);
    }

    return $total;
}

foreach($res2 as $email) {
    // Return the number of success emails
    $total = send_email($this->email, array(
        'email' => $email,
        'fromemail' => $fromemail,
        'fromname' => $fromname,
        'body' => $emailDesign2
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please look at google app password service... because in google account setting, 2-step authentication would be activated, my codeignitor setting has been worked successfully and the settings are like this...

```
    "protocol"   => "smtp",
    "smtp_host"  => "ssl://smtp.gmail.com",
    "smtp_port"  => "465",
    "smtp_timeout"  => "7",
    "smtp_user"  => $email_settings->user_email,
    "smtp_pass"  => "xxxxxxx", // please take this from google app password services...
    "starttls"   => TRUE,
    "charset"    => "utf-8",
    "mailtype"   => "html", // or text/plain
    "wordwrap"   => TRUE,
    "newline"    => "\r\n",
    "validate"    => FALSE,
    "smtp_keep_alive"    => TRUE
```

and also other fields are there like from, to, subejct, and message...

thanks to be your kindness for your attention and interests....